# $\int \sqrt{1+\sin ^2 x} dx$ an elliptic integral?

Tags: integration

It seems to be an elliptic integral of the second kind, but when $k=i$? This is going by the definition that $E(\theta,k)=\int_{0}^{\theta} \sqrt{1-k^2 \sin^2x}dx$. That seems a bit off.

Or is this not one at all due to the indefinite nature of the integral?

Comment: Yes it is. Where is your problem with that ? Cheers

Comment: I was under the impression that $k$ is to be a real number, or am I mistaken with that?

Comment: $\sqrt{1+\sin^2 x} = \sqrt{2 - \cos^2 x}$

Comment: You could probably type "elliptic integral of the second kind" into the web, and find an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Is $\displaystyle\int\sqrt{1+\sin^2x}~dx~$ an elliptic integral?*

Yes, it is. In fact, that's how [elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) came into being, by trying to compute the [arc length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating) of the sine or cosine function, which is precisely what you have done here.

> *But when $k=i$? That seems a bit off.*

It does, doesn't it? But [why](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) is that such a [shock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_identity) for you? :-) Even trigonometric functions can be written as [exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Relationship_to_exponential_function_and_complex_numbers) and/or [logarithmic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms) expressions containing imaginary arguments, so why would this be any different?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the elliptic integral of the second kind $E(\phi,m):=\int\limits _0^\theta \sqrt{1-m \sin^2 x}\,dx$. (Note that my convention will be to write in terms of $m=k^2$ rather than $k$ itself.) Naively, the range of allowed $m$ is $m\in [0,1]$. The question posted above is then a special case of the following: What is the meaning of $E(\theta,-m)$ for $0\leq m \leq 1$?

To answer this, We can manipulate $E(\theta,-m)$ into a more recognizable form. Substituting $u=\pi/2-x$, we have $$1+m \sin^2 x =1+m(1-\sin^2 u)=(1+m)\left(1-\frac{m}{1+m}\sin^2 u\right)$$ and therefore

\begin{align}
E(\theta,-m)
&=(1+m)^{1/2}\int\limits _{\pi/2-\theta}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-\frac{m}{1+m}\sin^2 u}\,du \\
&=(1+m)^{1/2} E\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{m}{1+m}\right)-(1+m)^{1/2} E\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta,\frac{m}{1+m}\right).
\end{align}

Note that the function in the first term is in fact the *complete* elliptic integral $E\left(\frac{m}{m+1}\right).$ For the special case of $m=1$, we conclude that

\begin{align}
E(\theta,-1)
&=\int_{0}^\theta \sqrt{1+\sin^2 x}\,dx \\
&= \sqrt{2}E\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\sqrt{2}E\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta,\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{2}\int_{\pi/2-\theta}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2 x}\,dx.
\end{align}